# set icon to datagridview cells per db values

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying set icon to datagridview cells per my db vaules that are 1,0 
i am use this code (copied from this site!)

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows)

{ DataGridViewImageCell cell = row.Cells[8] as DataGridViewImageCell;

if  row.Cells[8]==1)
                cell.Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.ok;

if  row.Cells[8]==0)
                cell.Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.notOK;

}
```

but compiler shows  this error:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
Message="Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

What is wrong in that code?

Comment: assign the image and check cell value are same?

Comment: 4example, i want to set green tick icon for 1 values and red stop icon for 0 values, how can i do this operation by code after binding data in datagridview or after fetching from db in dataTable??  tanx

Comment: did you try my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DT.Columns.Add("c",System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewImageCell);

for (int i = 0; i < DT.Rows.Count; i++) { if (DT.Rows[i][8].ToString() == "1")

DT.Rows[i]["a"] = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.ok;

else

row.Cells[8].Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.notOK;

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think you want this

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows)

{ 

if  (row.Cells[8]==1)
  {
      row.Cells[8]=new DataGridViewImageCell();
      row.Cells[8].Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.ok;
  }
if  (row.Cells[8]==0)
  {
       row.Cells[8]=new DataGridViewImageCell();
       row.Cells[8].Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.notOK;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("a", "Image");
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["a"] = new DataGridViewImageCell();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["a"].Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.Config;
                }
                else
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["a"].Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.Config;

                }
            }
```

Comment: Tanx for ur reply dear SATSON , i found this problem solution : when databinding of datagridview completed, must create a new DataGridViewImageCell type column and fill it per number column, then hide number column but i dont know translate it to c# code, i try this code :